# How to discover the columns for a given index or key in MonetDB

Tags: sql, monetdb

MonetDB seems to support a fairly comprehensive set of **system catalog views** in order to discover the schema structure of the database.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a SQL query that will obtain the **set of columns for a given key or index**.  Here are the system tables/views are reported by the Tables table:

schemas
types
functions
args
sequences
dependencies
connections
_tables
_columns
keys
idxs
triggers
objects
tables
columns
db_user_info
users
user_role
auths
privileges
queryhistory
callhistory
querylog
systemfunctions

I tried dependencies, but the IDs don't seem to match up.  BTW, I did try looking in the source code, but I haven't yet found where the system views are created and maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two and a half years later, because I was intrigued by the question: You can indeed find the columns for a given key using the poorly named "objects" table.

For example, consider the following table

```
CREATE TABLE indextest (a INT, b INT);
ALTER TABLE indextest ADD CONSTRAINT indextest_pk PRIMARY KEY (a);
ALTER TABLE indextest ADD CONSTRAINT indextest_uq UNIQUE (a, b);
```

Now let's  find out which columns belong to `indextest_uq`:

```
SELECT idxs.id AS index_id, columns.id AS column_id, tables.name AS table_name, columns.name AS column_name, columns.type AS column_type 
FROM idxs JOIN objects ON idxs.id=objects.id JOIN tables ON idxs.table_id=tables.id JOIN columns ON idxs.table_id=columns.table_id AND objects.name=columns.name 
WHERE idxs.name='indextest_uq';
```

The result of this query looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
| index_id | column_id | table_name | column_name | column_type |
+==========+===========+============+=============+=============+
|     6446 |      6438 | indextest  | a           | int         |
|     6446 |      6439 | indextest  | b           | int         |
+----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Obviously, more information from the `columns` and `tables` tables could be included by extending the `SELECT` part of the query.